# Login With Facebook With Different User

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

This seems to be a common issue amongst app developers, similar to the problems caused when trying to log out of Twitter as well.

The problem I am having is I can not seem to get Facebook to "get rid of" and forget my user credentials when I log out.

I have successfully been able to login and logout of Facebook with my app so far. **HOWEVER**, after I log out, Facebook takes me directly to Safari (like it should) but then uses my info from my previous login to automatically **re-log me in**. I want to know where Facebook stores this information locally **or** how I can reset this information when I log out.

FYI: I am aware of methods such as `[[FBSession activeSession] closeAndClearTokenInformation];`, or even

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://m.facebook.com"];
        NSArray *cookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookiesForURL:url];
        for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookies)
        {
            [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] deleteCookie:cookie];
        }

        NSLog(@"Logged out of facebook");

        NSHTTPCookieStorage *fbcookies = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
        for (NSHTTPCookie* cookie2 in
             [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]) {
            [fbcookies deleteCookie:cookie2];
        }
```

...yet none of these **remove** the users login information to make way for a new login.

I find it quite strange that neither programmers or Facebook developer staff members can provide the solution to this. Hopefully someone on *here* knows how to do it for real. Thanks!

Comment: The cookie storage you reference above only applies to the embedded webview, and does not apply to Safari.app. When the SDK switches to Safari.app to do SSO, it's using the cookies there to auto-log you in. There's no mechanism to clear those cookies from your app (or via the SDK). If you want to log in as a different user, you need to manually log out of Facebook in Safari.app first.

Answer (score 0):

I also found no way to make it in code. The only way to enter another credentials in the application with Facebook 4.x is to log out from Facebook in Safari.

Comment: right. i reworked how i authenticate the user however and managed to quite nicely remove the users FB info

Comment: @WillVonUllrich How can I make it?